# Не работает Insert запрос

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "INSERT INTO 'accounts' SET name = '".$data['name']."', password ='".$password."', mail ='".$data['mail']."', sex ='".$data['sex']."', model = '".$data['model']."', regip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', referal = '".$data['referal']."', datareg = '".$time."' ";
```

Не работает запрос. Остальное по умолчанию прописано. Помогите!

Comment: А ошибки-то какие выдает. Если вы уверены что проблема в запросе, выведете `var_dump($query)` и попробуйте запрос вручную.

Comment: Но чуйка мне подсказывает что у вас в ваших переменных где-то затоилась одинарная ковычка (') - если таковая будет например в `$data['referal']` - то запрос действительно не будет выполнен из-за синтаксической ошибки.

Comment: $data['referal'] - Пустое у меня

Comment: я привел как пример, сделайте сразу после этой строчки `var_dump($query);` и покажите результат.

Comment: string(215) "INSERT INTO 'accounts' SET name = 'Leonardo_Catton', password ='ca7b8fe83e05157d144f41bc8ae2e41e', mail ='halinmaxim@gmail.com', sex ='1', model = '', regip = '127.0.0.1', referal = '', datareg = '2018-07-27 19:41' "

Comment: Хм, model не передалось, прикольненько, да и referal тоже

Comment: название таблицы ограничено обратными кавычками?

Comment: Уже нашёл в чём ошибка

Comment: @МаксимХалин дайте угадаю, наверное вот тут? `'accounts'`?

Comment: Нет, model не выводиться. Сейчас буду решать

Comment: accounts в обратных кавычках

Comment: Ну вот. Ещё один любитель бежать сразу на SO, а не запросить у mysql последнюю ошибку. Что с вами такое?!

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в кавычках названии таблицы, уберите их.

https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/